# Cant assign a variable through connect method in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-signals, qt-slot

When trying to connect a button press to the assignment of a variable, PyCharm refuses to accept the syntax, stating `Can't assign to function call` with red syntax underlining.

Here is the following code:

`self.button.clicked.connect(lambda : outside_object.username = self.username)`

How can I assign a variable without calling something similar to a setter method such as `self.button.clicked.connect(lambda: outside_object.assign_username(self.username))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
self.button.clicked.connect(lambda _ : setattr(outside_object, 'username', self.username))
```